# Facebook like button and facebook page not connected?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

I created an facebook app and added a like button to my page. I also created a facebook page and it is connected to the facebook app. As it seems, the like button on the external page only likes the link and does not count towards the likes of the facebook page.

So the like button and the facebook page seem to be two separate things. Is this intended like this or did I fail to connect them correctly? Also see this screenshot: (The like button on the external page and the like button on the facebook page seem to be different events)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the url of your facebook page , for the `data-href` parameter of your like button code. . so that the like button will show the number of likes for your facebook page and also add to the page likes when someone clicks the like button .

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/pepalo" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

you can generate like button code [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)

[image]